# Cron не работает по расписанию ls

Tags: linux

По заданию нужно было сделайте так, чтобы в xx минут xx часов автоматически выполнилась утилита `ls` и вывелась строка текста «Lab rab 3. Zadanie 18». Учтите, что вывод будет
осуществляться не на экран, а в файл: /var/spool/mail/student (xx минут xx часов –
ближайшие несколько минут).
я сделал с помощью cron
написал так `crontab -e` после у меня попросило открыть в редакторе я открыл в nano вписал команду

```
* * * * * ls > /var/spool/mail/student && echo "Lab rab 3. Zadanie 18" >> /var/spool/mail/student
```

в которой по моей логике каждую минуту будет автоматически вписывать команда `ls` ну вобщем как по заданию проверил что команда есть `crontab -l` но все равно ждал минут две после проверяю `cat` и путь с `sudo` нет ничего пояснить в чем дело делал все в оболочки ubuntu с помощью виндового terminal застрял на этой задачке

Comment: так nano сохранил?

Comment: да сочетанием клавиш

Comment: А что за оболочка ubuntu с помощью виндового terminal? Возможно крон просто не запускается. Убунта у вас где? На локальном компе? На удалённом сервере?

Comment: 22.04.3 lts не знаю в чем проблема

Comment: ubuntu на пк я с пк и делаю с помощь wsl

Comment: Ну вот, cron не запущен скорее всего. Гуглите `wsl cron start` (например https://stackoverflow.com/a/60262632/7781204).

Comment: cron работает прекрасно проверил файлы но вот почему то пишет когда используешь cat типа нет такой дериктории но в виндовом проводнике все эти папки и файл есть вот что в файле содержиться 
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/tmp/crontab.fTvd0i/crontab installed on Fri Mar  8 17:51:23 2024)
# (Cron version -- $Id: crontab.c,v 2.13 1994/01/17 03:20:37 vixie Exp $)
* * * * * ls > /var/spool/mail/student && echo "Lab rab 3. Zadanie 18" >> /var/spool/mail/student

Comment: @ITBEGINER Как вы убедились, что cron работает прекрасно? `ps aux | grep cron` показывает процесс cron'а?  cron -- это программа, которая работает в фоне (незаметно для вас) и запускает задачи по вашему расписанию. Обычно она запускается при старте системы (но не под виндой). crontab -- это не cron, а инструмент конфигурирования расписания. Если вы использовали crontab для редактирования расписания, то это ещё не значит, что cron запущен и обрабатывает ваше расписание.

Comment: значит я не прав

Comment: я ввел sudo service cron status пишет что он работает

Comment: ps aux | grep cron  мне показал только root и мое имя пользователя

Comment: Все решил все работает моя проблема была в неправильном синтаксисе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все решил все работает моя проблема была в неправильном синтаксисе. Понял я это благодаря тесту.

Comment: Так что именно было неправильно? Приведите в ответе правильный вызов и напишите, что именно было не так. Иначе ваш ответ бесполезен.

Comment: Решение заключалось в том что в редакторе нано были лишние пробелы которые сбивали путь я начал проверять по тесту, а именно вводил */2 * * * * ls >> путь итд потом проверил с помощью cat путь и все работало как надо

Answer (score 0):

Задайте на /var/spool/mail/student права по маске 777 (sudo chmod 777 /var/spool/mail/student)

Comment: решил проще там работает прекрасно нашел ошибку когда просто сделал тест проверку работы cron